# How can I apply fade transition on svg's linear gradient when carousel index changed?

Tags: css, vue.js, svg, nuxt.js

I have built a fade carousel which also requires to change the color of an inline svg on top of it (an overlay decoration, basically). The expected result should be similar to this:

[image: the expected result]

I tried several ways to achive this kind of fade transition using `transition: fill 0.2s ease`, `animation` and `keyframes` but it doesn't work. Instead of transitioning, it just changed the color instantly.

[image: implementation]

I defined the linear gradient inside the SVG and use something like this `fill: url(#primary)` to `fill: url(#blue)` to change the color for every classes because I couldn't find a way to apply gradient inside the `path` via CSS.

I'm wondering what is the proper way to do this..

`hero-overlay.svg`

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="728.844" height="1023.046" viewBox="0 0 728.844 1023.046">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="primary" x1="0.226" y1="-0.045" x2="0.544" y2="0.549" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#2930fb" stop-opacity="0.7"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#15187e" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="blue" x1="0.226" y1="-0.045" x2="0.544" y2="0.549" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#54a0ff" stop-opacity="0.7"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#15187e" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="purple" x1="0.226" y1="-0.045" x2="0.544" y2="0.549" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#5f27cd" stop-opacity="0.7"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#15187e" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path d="M105.818,23.9c219.16-2.006,219.411-2.257,298.9,200.592C447.6,333.316,488.972,442.638,531.851,550.456,582,675.826,632.153,880.8,692.083,1033c82.5-245.223.426,0,0,0-138.417,1.5-251.256,58.55-313.443-72.836-51.907-109.322-93.281-223.659-138.166-335.991C161.235,428.1,83.251,232.017,0,23.9Z" transform="translate(0 -23.551)" fill="url(#a)"/>
</svg>
```

`Vector.vue` (svg loaded using [@nuxtjs/svg](https://github.com/nuxt-community/svg-module#nuxtjssvg))

```html
<template>
  <div class="vector" v-html="source"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    file: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    source() {
      const source = require(`~/static/vectors/${this.file}.svg?raw`)
      return source
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`Hero.vue`

```html
<template>
  <header class="hero">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="textbox">
          <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
            <template v-for="(slide, i) in slides">
              <div class="slide-content" :key="slide.id" v-if="current == i">
                <h1 class="punchline">
                  {{ slide.title }}
                </h1>
                <p class="caption">{{ slide.caption }}</p>
              </div>
            </template>
          </transition>
          <NuxtLink class="link" to="/">
            <div class="icon-wrapper">
              <Icon icon="chevron-right" />
            </div>
          </NuxtLink>
        </div>
        <div class="indicator">
          <span
            v-for="(slide, i) in slides"
            :key="slide.id"
            :class="{ active: current == i }"
            class="item"
            @click="jump(i)"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- this is the overlay -->
    <Vector class="overlay" :class="color" file="hero-overlay" />
  </header>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      current: 0,
      slides: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Slide 001',
          caption: 'say something',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'Slide 002',
          caption: 'say something',
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: 'Slide 003',
          caption: 'say something',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    color() {
      if (this.current == 1) return 'blue'
      if (this.current == 2) return 'purple'
      return 'default'
    },
  },
  methods: {
    jump(index) {
      this.current = index
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.overlay::v-deep svg path {
  transition: fill 1s ease-out;
  /* transition: all 1s ease-out; doesn't work either */
}

.overlay.default ::v-deep svg path {
  fill: url(#primary);
}

.overlay.blue ::v-deep svg path {
  fill: url(#blue);
}

.overlay.purple ::v-deep svg path {
  fill: url(#purple);
}
</style>
```

Comment: you'd need to use a single gradient and transition the stops

Comment: @RobertLongson , I also thinking that way, but I don't know how to control the stops from vue side, would you please help me with this?

Comment: I don't know vue either. Your best bet for this is SMIL really.

Comment: ah okay, thank you so much, I'll have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to do this, thanks @Robert for pointing out about the use of `linearGradient`. The solution for this is to use `watch` and `ref` property and listen to the new values. I had to refactor the script a little bit and removed the `.blue, .purple, .primary` class from the css.

The final script looks like this:

`hero-overlay.svg` (simplified, it now only use 1 `<linearGradient>`)

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="728.844" height="1023.046" viewBox="0 0 728.844 1023.046">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="a" x1="0.226" y1="-0.045" x2="0.544" y2="0.549" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#2930fb" stop-opacity="0.7"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#15187e" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path d="M105.818,23.9c219.16-2.006,219.411-2.257,298.9,200.592C447.6,333.316,488.972,442.638,531.851,550.456,582,675.826,632.153,880.8,692.083,1033c82.5-245.223.426,0,0,0-138.417,1.5-251.256,58.55-313.443-72.836-51.907-109.322-93.281-223.659-138.166-335.991C161.235,428.1,83.251,232.017,0,23.9Z" transform="translate(0 -23.551)" fill="url(#a)"/>
</svg>
```

`Hero.vue`

```html
<template>
  <!-- The rest stays the same -->

  <!-- I added `ref` to this component -->
  <Vector ref="overlay" class="overlay" file="hero-overlay" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  // data stays the same

  computed: {
    // Instead of using plain text 'blue, purple, default',
    // we can just use the HEX since it no longer be used
    // as a class name.
    color() {
      if (this.current == 1) return '#54a0ff' // 'blue'
      if (this.current == 2) return '#5f27cd' // 'purple'
      return '#2930fb' // 'default'
    },
  },
  watch: {
    // Then watch the value for changes and use it right
    // away. First, we gotta target the first `<stop>`
    // since the second one are always transparent
    // then set the attribute color to match the current
    color(val) {
      this.$refs.overlay.$el
        .querySelector('linearGradient > stop:nth-of-type(1)')
        .setAttribute('stop-color', val)
    }
  },

  // methods stays the same
}
</script>

<style scoped>
/*
  The css are simplified to this.
  
  We use `::v-deep` because it was scoped
  and vue cannot simply find the element directly.
*/
.overlay ::v-deep linearGradient stop {
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
</style>
```